# Python Exit From Script and Return to Main

Tags: python, exit

I'm trying to make a simple text based game to improve my knowledge with Python, and I've created a little fighting system that's located in another Python file.  The way I go about calling this system is by importing the file and then calling the start function.  The problem I'm running into is actually getting the script to stop and return to the main script so the player can continue the game.  Here's the relevant code so far:

**Fight.py**

```
def fight():
    global enemy_health
    global enemy

    if health <= 0:
        print "You have died!"
        return False
    elif enemy_health <= 0:
        print "You have killed the %s!" % enemy
        return True

    print "You have %d health." % health
    print "The enemy has %d health." % enemy_health

    while True:
        choice = raw_input("> ")
        if choice == "stab":
            pDamage = random.randrange(2, 4)
            enemy_health -= pDamage
            print "You stab the %s and deal %d damage!" % (enemy, pDamage)
            enemyTurn()
        elif choice == "slash":
            pDamage = random.randrange(1, 6)
            enemy_health -= pDamage
            print "You slash the %s and deal %d damage!" % (enemy, pDamage)
            enemyTurn()
        elif choice == "chop":
            pDamage = random.randrange(2, 7)
            enemy_health -= pDamage
            print "You chop the %s and deal %d damage!" % (enemy, pDamage)
            enemyTurn()
        else:
            print "You can slash, stab, or chop the enemy!"
```

**Game.py**

```
elif command == "look":
    fight.start()
    fightResults = fight.fight()
    if fightResults == True:
        print "You've won the game!"
    elif fightResults == False:
        print "You've lost the game!"
        exit(0)
```

So, the problem is that when the player wins or loses and Fight.py returns a value, the entire game exits.  Any help fixing this problem would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to `break` from your `while` loop.

Comment: Modules don't work like this. It's not clear what you actually want to do, given the limited code from `Game.py` you've posted.

Comment: It exits because you are calling exit(0) if `fight` return False. Don't do it and it won't exit.

Comment: Sorry about the answer I misread some stuff in your question.

Comment: Are there any return statements in or after the while loop in your fight.fight function?

Comment: I'm sorry for the lack of code that I posted, but since I was posting from my Mac at school (the thing really sucks for programming, thankfully I've got my Linux box at home) I had to manually remove line numbers from Vim and it was taking a really long time, so I only posted a bit of code.  What I'm trying to do is have Fight.py exit and then call a function from Game.py to continue the game.  I didn't actually create the function and only did a print statement to see if it worked, which it didn't.  Hopefully this cleared up some confusion, but if really necessary I can post the full code.